# How to use a NSPredicate to filter an array of objects that contain NSMetadataitems

Tags: ios, nspredicate

I have a class. Lets call that class `MyObject`. `MyObject` has a property called item that is a `NSMetadataItem`.

`NSMetadataItem`s have an attribute called `NSMetadataItemFSNameKey` that can be fetched by using this:

```
NSString *fileName = [myMetadataItem valueForAttribute: NSMetadataItemFSNameKey];
```

Now I have an array or `MyObjects` and I want to find what object has an item which `NSMetadataItemFSNameKey` is the one I am looking for.

OK, I can iterate thru the array using this code:

```
  for (MyObject *oneObj in array) {
    NSString *oneFileName = [oneObj.item valueForAttribute:NSMetadataItemFSNameKey];
    if ([oneFileName isEqualToString:fileNameItem]) {
      // found, do something
    }
  }
```

but I am trying to find if it is possible to do that using `NSPredicates` and filtering?

Is that possible?

Comment: You can use a `predicateWithBlock:` method of `NSPredicate`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"item.%K = %@", NSMetadataItemFSNameKey, fileNameItem];
NSArray *filteresArray = [array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

Typed in Safari.

Comment: brilliant. I never realized one can use dot notation and use predicates to search for attributes. I thought only properties could be searched like that. THANKS!

Comment: Attributes are properties. It is hard for a piece of code to detect, whether a property is a declared property or not. There is no obvious difference for the user of the class at runtime.